# why my loss and accuracy plots are slightly shaky?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I built a Bi-LSTM model, which tries to predict certain categories based on a given word. For example, the word "smile" should be predicted by "friendly".

However, after training, the model with 100 samples per 10 categories (1000 in total), at the time of plotting the accuracy and loss, these two are slightly shaky continuously. Why does this occur? Increasing the number of samples causes underfitting.

### Model

```py
def build_model(vocab_size, embedding_dim=64, input_length=30):
    print('\nbuilding the model...\n')

    model = tf.keras.Sequential([
        tf.keras.layers.Embedding(input_dim=(vocab_size + 1), output_dim=embedding_dim, input_length=input_length),
        tf.keras.layers.Bidirectional(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(rnn_units, return_sequences=True, dropout=0.2)),
        tf.keras.layers.Bidirectional(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(rnn_units, return_sequences=True, dropout=0.2)),
        tf.keras.layers.GlobalMaxPool1D(),
        tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.1),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(64, activation='tanh', kernel_regularizer=tf.keras.regularizers.L2(l2=0.01)),
        
        # softmax output layer
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax')
    ])

    # optimizer & loss
    opt = 'RMSprop' #tf.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=1e-4)
    loss = 'categorical_crossentropy'

    # Metrics
    metrics = ['accuracy', 'AUC','Precision', 'Recall']

    # compile model
    model.compile(optimizer=opt, 
                  loss=loss,
                  metrics=metrics)
    
    model.summary()

    return model
```

### training

```py
def train(model, x_train, y_train, x_validation, y_validation,
          epochs, batch_size=32, patience=5, 
          verbose=2, monitor_es='accuracy', mode_es='auto', restore=True,
          monitor_mc='val_accuracy', mode_mc='max'):
    
    # callback
    early_stopping = tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor=monitor_es,
                                                      verbose=1, mode=mode_es, restore_best_weights=restore,
                                                      min_delta=1e-3, patience=patience)
    
    model_checkpoint = tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint('tfjsmode.h5', monitor=monitor_mc, mode=mode_mc,      
                                                          verbose=1, save_best_only=True)

    keras_callbacks = [early_stopping, model_checkpoint]

    # train model
    history = model.fit(x_train, y_train,
                        batch_size=batch_size, epochs=epochs, verbose=verbose,
                        validation_data=(x_validation, y_validation),
                        callbacks=keras_callbacks)
    return history
```

### ACCURACY & LOSS

[image]

[image]

#### BATCH SIZE

Currently the batch size is set to 16, if I increase the batch size to 64 with 2500 samples per category, the final plots will will result in underfitting.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Increasing batch size should decrease shaking and decreasing batch size should increase shaking. The smaller the batch size the more variance there will be between the means of the batches, fluctuating the mean your model is optimizing for (hence shaking).

Comment: @Kosaro should I keep it with small batch size? and how can this fluctuation affect the model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments the smaller the batch size the more variance of the mean for the batches which then appear in more fluctuation in the loss. I typically use a batch size of 80 since I have a fairly large memory capacity. You are using the ModelCheckpoint callback and saving the model with the best validation accuracy. It is better to save the model with the lowest  validation loss. You say increasing the number of samples leads to under fitting. That seems rather strange. Usually more samples results in better accuracy.

Comment: currently I'm saving the model with lowest validation loss, thank you for the suggestion. I will attach the plots with higher batch_size, so you can see and tell me what you think.

Comment: you were monitoring mc which was equal to the validation accuracy. Would like to see what happens when you increase the number of training samples

Comment: plots updated with 2500 samples per category and batch size set to 64

Comment: hmm accuracy is rather low

Comment: Batch sizes that are too big can lead to the model getting stuck in a local minimum. Smaller batch sizes should give you more accurate models since the "shakiness" helps it exit those minimums and find a better solution. Smaller batch sizes give you better models but take longer to train.